# How to save the image from the server and display it?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want a Code to save the selected image from the server temporarily
To review it on another page :

1-**Save the image with image id** (not in gallery, because I will Upload it again).

image link

```
"http://10.0.2.2/test/upload/"+snapshot.data[i]["post_image"]
```

and image id link

```
"http://10.0.2.2/test/upload/"+snapshot.data[i]["id_image"]
```

2-**Show this image with its id in Container on another page.**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you get the image URL from the server and want to show these images for multi-page.

Creating the `static` image variable type is an alternative.

example:

```
class Example {
  static String imageLink = "Your image link",
      linkId = "Your link id";
}

void update(imageLink,linkId){
  Example.imageLink = imageLink;
  Example.linkId = linkId;
}

void using(){
  print(Example.imageLink);
  print(Example.linkId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is to save the image in state, a simple approach would be to use a `StatefulWidget` and `setState((){});`

here's an example

```dart
class SomeWidget extends StatefulWidget{

...

}

class SomeWidgetState extends State<SomeWidget>{

String? imageLink;
String? imageId;



Future<void> getLink(){

    /// get the link 

    setState( () {

    imageLink =  "http://10.0.2.2/test/upload/"+snapshot.data[i]["post_image"];
    linkId = "http://10.0.2.2/test/upload/"+snapshot.data[i]["id_image"];
   });
 } 

...
Navigator.push(builder: MaterialPageRouteBuilder((context) => AnotherScreen(imageLink, imageId)));

}
```

if you have more items to store in the state, would recommend using a state management library like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider)

Comment: thank you ,
this is right but not work with me because I have to put 2 selected image in 1 page,

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't get you, could you elaborate more ?

Comment: I want to put two photos in one screen . Same idea (before and after). The problem is when I add the first picture the second disappears, and when I add the second the first disappears.. Mostly because the page is reload ( 2 Navigator )